# how to ORDER BY date in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

please can someone help, i cant find anything on stack overflow that can help me and im a noob at this, i want to order the foreach loop by date in either ASC or DESC, here is my code :

```
<?php foreach($all_weddings as $wedding_id): ?>
  <?php  echo '<div class="' . (++$count%5 ? "wedding_client_odd" : "wedding_client_even") . '">'; ?>
  <?php $wedding = new data($wedding_id); ?>
  <?php $all_images = data_helper::get_links($wedding->id,'image'); ?>
  <?php  $image = new data($all_images[0]); ?>
  <div class="wedding_image">
   <?php
     image_helper::display_image($image->id,176,140,'image_gallery_thumb rounded-corners');  
   ?>
  </div>
  <div class="wedding_content">
   <div class="content_height">
    <h2 class="grey"><?php echo $wedding->title; ?></h2>
   </div>
   <p class="grey"><?php echo date("j F Y", strtotime($wedding->date)); ?></p>
  </div>
 </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

here is a dump of `$all_weddings`

```
array(32) { [0]=> string(4) "2012" [1]=> string(4) "2009" [2]=> string(4) "2007" [3]=> string(4) "2005" [4]=> string(4) "2002" [5]=> string(4) "2000" [6]=> string(4) "1998" [7]=> string(4) "1995" [8]=> string(4) "1993" [9]=> string(4) "1991" [10]=> string(4) "1989" [11]=> string(4) "1987" [12]=> string(4) "1985" [13]=> string(4) "1983" [14]=> string(4) "1981" [15]=> string(4) "1980" [16]=> string(4) "1978" [17]=> string(4) "1976" [18]=> string(4) "1974" [19]=> string(4) "1972" [20]=> string(4) "1970" [21]=> string(4) "1968" [22]=> string(4) "1966" [23]=> string(4) "1964" [24]=> string(4) "1962" [25]=> string(4) "1960" [26]=> string(4) "1958" [27]=> string(4) "1956" [28]=> string(4) "1954" [29]=> string(4) "1952" [30]=> string(4) "1945" [31]=> string(4) "1943" }
```

Comment: you don't order inside the loop. Whatever array you're going to be looping on, you sort it FIRST, then loop on the sorted version.

Comment: could you show us dump of `$all_weddings` please?

Comment: Also you dont need a `<?php .... ?>` around every line of php code. Just one before the first statement and one after the last php statement. **thats almost unreadable**

Comment: Kim Alexander how do i do a dump on $all_weddings?

Comment: marc B can you show me how to sort it? sorry im still noob at this

Comment: put line : `var_dump($all_weddings); exit();` right above `foreach` and copy here the outputs

Comment: ok i updated my question with the output

Comment: so your id is YEAR numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're pulling your data from a relational database, you need to order your results in the SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM weddings ORDER BY date ASC;
```

You can't, or shouldn't order things in a loop. You could also sort your results in PHP code prior to looping the results, but that's hackish and not the best way to do it. Pull the data from the database how you want it ordered and you're done.

Comment: :-) how did you find out that is database?

Comment: I didn't that why I used the word "assuming." ;-)

Answer (score 0):

so try this way:

```
<?php
  sort($all_weddings);
  foreach($all_weddings as $wedding_id) { 
  echo '<div class="' . (++$count%5 ? "wedding_client_odd" : "wedding_client_even") . '">'; 
  $wedding = new data($wedding_id); 
  $all_images = data_helper::get_links($wedding->id,'image');
  $image = new data($all_images[0]); ?>
  <div class="wedding_image">
   <?php
     image_helper::display_image($image->id,176,140,'image_gallery_thumb rounded-corners');  
   ?>
  </div>
  <div class="wedding_content">
   <div class="content_height">
    <h2 class="grey"><?php echo $wedding->title; ?></h2>
   </div>
   <p class="grey"><?php echo date("j F Y", strtotime($wedding->date)); ?></p>
  </div>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you for helping Kim, but this way is still mixing it up

Comment: so "2012" still coming first??

Comment: wait let me show you here is a link, http://dorp.peridemo.co.za/wedding_category/view/ons_bruidspare, i want those photos sorted according to the date on them in either ASC or DESC, and as you can see now its mixed up

Comment: hey :-))) those numbers "2012", "1943"...etc...  are years?? on your page there is a photo "26 March 2016" how could it possible?

Comment: lol i have no idea, do you think you can still help with this? and im using a datepicker in the backend to choose the date, in my database i have a date field where the 26 March 2016 is in and where all the other dates are in that you see underneath each photo, the table in the database has an "id", "title" and "date" field, hope this helps?

Comment: where id initialization of `$all_weddings` could you show that fragment?

Comment: sorry i dont understand?

Comment: you mean this : $all_weddings = data_helper::get_links($wedding_category->id,'wedding','parent','A','`data`.`id` DESC');

Comment: its a custom CMS that one of my friends wrote for me, but sadly he passed away

Comment: if you want i can upload it somewhere and you can test it live? then afterwards you can take a copy of the CMS for yourself

Comment: no, thank you, I don't need that, I just want to know the name, to check documentation for that ` data_helper::get_links` function

Comment: as far as i kno its a class, i can paste the class here

Comment: I didn't ask for that, I've asked for the Framework or CMS NAME you use in this project

Comment: there is no documentation on it, because it is a custom build CMS